# Gradle classpath, specify directory instead of individual jars

Tags: java, postgresql, gradle

I'm new to building projects with Gradle, and I'm hoping someone here can help me figure out a little problem I'm having specifying an external jar dependency.

Right now, the only way I can get my Gradle-built jar to run is by specifying the dependency in my build.gradle file (here the Postgres JDBC driver) explicitly, like so:

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes (
                "Main-Class": "<redacted>",
                "Class-Path": "/lib/java/postgresql-9.4.1209.jar"
        )
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have to specify exactly which jar I'm using. This is fine when I only have a few external deps, but I'm worried I'll have a massive classpath specification once I've got four or five external deps.

Is there a way to simply specify a folder it should look in instead of naming each jar? I want so be able to do something like this:

`"Class-Path": "/lib/java/*"`

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Why aren't you using the standard dependency management?

Comment: Check out the [application](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) plugin. It builds launch scripts for several platforms; these scripts set the class path to include your dependency jars.

Comment: I'm unsure what the "standard dependency management" is. Could you explain? Whenever I build a jar with Gradle it never bundles the deps I specify in the dependencies block with the resulting jar, so I thought I needed to specify them all at runtime.

Comment: To include all jars in directory, add directory with trailing /.  See notes from http://todayguesswhat.blogspot.in/2011/03/jar-manifestmf-class-path-referencing.html (did not try.. )